# Find Substring - SQL

Tags: sql, substring, querying

I need to find a substring that is in a text field that is actually partially xml.  I tried converting it to xml and then use the .value method but to  no avail.

The element(substring)  I am looking for is a method name that looks like this:

`AssemblyQualifiedName="IPMGlobal.CRM2011.IPM.CustomWorkflowActivities.ProcessChildRecords,`

where the method at the end "ProcessChildRecords" could be another name such as "SendEmail".  I know I can use the "**CustomWorkflowActivities.**" and the `,` (comma) to find the substring (method name) but not sure how to accomplish it.  In addition, there may be more that one instance listed of the `**"CustomWorkflowActvities.<method>"**`

Some Clarifications:

Below is my original query.  It returns that first occurrence in each row but no additional.  For example I might have in the string **'...IPM.CustomWorkflowActivities.ProcessChildRecords...'**  and 
**'...IPM.CustomWorkflowActivities.GetworkflowContext...'**

The current query only returns **Approve Time Process,
ipm_mytimesheetbatch,
ProcessChildRecords**

`SELECT WF.name WFName,
       (
             SELECT TOP 1 Name
             FROM entity E
             WHERE WF.primaryentity = E.ObjectTypeCode
       ) Entity,
       Convert(xml, xaml) Xaml,
       SUBSTRING(xaml, Charindex('CustomWorkflowActivities.', xaml) + Len('CustomWorkflowActivities.'), Charindex(', IPMGlobal.CRM2011.IPM.CustomWorkflowActivities, Version=1.0.0.0', xaml) - Charindex('CustomWorkflowActivities.', xaml) - Len('CustomWorkflowActivities.'))

FROM FilteredWorkflow WF`

WHERE 1 = 1
      AND xaml LIKE '%customworkflowactivities%'
      AND statecodename = 'Activated'
      AND typename = 'Definition'
ORDER BY NAME

Comment: Please specify which RDBMs

Comment: Take a look at the `LIKE` operator in your RDBMS. Also, many RDBMSes have a regexp match function. It's not fast, though, because an an index by that field cannot be used.

Comment: What are the actual field contents? How did you try to extract the string and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Oracle` you could use `REGEXP` function:

```
WITH cte(t) as (
  SELECT 'AssemblyQualifiedName="IPMGlobal.CRM2011.IPM.CustomWorkflowActivities.ProcessChildRecords,' FROM dual
)
SELECT t,
     regexp_replace(t, '.*CustomWorkflowActivities.(.+)\,.*', '\1') AS r
FROM cte;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ca963ddb819463a0dc2fd71fc2194504)**

---

SQL Server:

```
WITH cte(t) as (
  SELECT 'AssemblyQualifiedName="IPMGlobal.CRM2011.IPM.CustomWorkflowActivities.ProcessChildRecords,asfdsa'
)
SELECT t,SUBSTRING(t, s, CHARINDEX(',', t, s)-s)
FROM (SELECT t, PATINDEX( '%CustomWorkflowActivities.%', t) + LEN('CustomWorkflowActivities.') AS s
      FROM cte 
) sub;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo 2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4bd9b4e10005c34a856b575593a1036e)**

Comment: Sorry SQL Server.

Comment: Very much on the right track but, Sorry I forgot to mention,  the xml may have more than one occurrence for method names.